# Create custom buttons with icon and text

Tags: android

I want to create two new custom buttons to use in my android application.

I want them to be like this:

- Icon on the left
- Text on the right for a button
- Another button with Icon on top and text on bottom

So basically I will have a png image stored in my resources that will be the button's icon. I will have another image as a 9patch stretchable as the button background. I tried something but the result is hideous, so I must be doing something wrong.

This code:

```
   <Button 
             android:layout_width="100px"
       android:layout_height="100px"
             android:drawableTop="@drawable/imgIcon"
             android:drawablePadding="2px"
             android:text="Text"
             android:background="@drawable/button_background"
             />
```

Later Edit:
If I make like suggested by Macarse bellow:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/yourid"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:text="Your text here" 
       android:drawableTop="@drawable/imgdonetracks">
</Button>
```

I get like in first image

If I make this change:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/yourid"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Your text here" 
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/imgdonetracks"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background">
   </Button>
```

everything get's wrong

Check image http://img255.imageshack.us/i/android3.png/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks so ugly because the button layout background has empty space but that has not been taken care of in the 9 patch image. Now I fixed with 9p editor as http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch and works fine

Answer (score 9):

```
<button android:id="@+id/yourid"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Your text here" 
        android:drawabletop="@drawable/[image]">
</button>
```

Here is the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableTop

Comment: I use this, but with android:background="@null"

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a bigger background resource which also fits the button width/height-ratio better?

Comment: No I haven't as I want to make the install kit as small as possible.